# 1990s VHS Movie. Beast promises to leave woman alive if she never tells anyone about it

Tags: story-identification, aliens, horror

Trying to find out which movie from approximately the 1990s contained this plot:  A woman sees a beast murder a man in an alley or street near her home.  She is terrified and promises the beast if he lets her live she will never tell anyone about seeing the beast.  Then the movie switches from "scary" to "romantic" as she meets the man of her dreams and hooks up with him.  It appears to be a "they lived happily ever after" but she has disturbing dreams of the murder and is an artist.  She draws or sketches the beast from the alley.  Eventually she tells her hubby what she promised not to tell and he turns into the beast to destroy her.  Can't remember fully but the beast might have possibly fallen from the sky (crashing like a meteor or alien landing in the opening scene).

Comment: Are you sure the protagonist isn't a man and the monster (a gargoyle) a woman? Because except for that, this is *exactly* the movie in Richard's answer.

Answer (score 11):

This could be the final segment of the [Tales From the Darkside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside:_The_Movie) movie;

> **Lover's Vow :** *A despondent artist named Preston (played by James
>   Remar) witnesses a gruesome murder committed by a gargoyle-like
>   monster. **The monster agrees to spare Preston's life as long as he
>   swears never to speak of what he saw and heard or describe the
>   monster's appearance to anyone**. The monster vanishes, leaving Preston
>   traumatized and confused, but bound by his oath never to talk about
>   the incident.*
>
> *After that night, Preston's life takes many turns for the better. He
>   meets a beautiful woman named Carola (played by Rae Dawn Chong), and
>   they fall in love, marry, and have two children. Preston's struggling
>   art career becomes wildly successful, and life seems promising, but he
>   is tormented by memories of his encounter with the monster, and his
>   vow of silence weighs on him. **One night he breaks down and tells
>   Carola about the monster, even showing her a statue he sculpted of it.
>   She appears upset; at first Preston assumes she thinks he's lying, but
>   then she lets out a heartbroken screech and reveals herself to be the
>   very same creature he met that night.***

Admittedly it's a **male** artist, not a female one but everything else in the story fits exactly.

---

**Warning : Video contains NSFW content (Creature effects)**

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what came to mind for me. The description exactly matches that segment except for the gender of the artist.